# How to reset on Ubuntu the terminal text color back to defaul once a SSH connection is closed

Tags: command-line, ssh, colors

**System: Ubuntu 20.04**

**My goal:** change terminal text color when I connect to SSH host and reset the terminal text color once the SSH connection is closed.

**Status:** I managed to change the text color when I establish the SSH connection (--> [How to change terminal colors when connecting to SSH hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/603909/how-to-change-terminal-colors-when-connecting-to-ssh-hosts))

`.bash_profile`

```
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo -e  '\033]10;#ff0000\007'
```

**Problem:** The terminal text color is not reset once I close the SSH connection.

Can this be done by editing `.bash_profile`? How can this be done not following the approach used in the mentioned article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need it to work for non-nested SSH sessions, you could put a corresponding line in your `~/.bash_logout` file, for example

```
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo -e  '\033]10;#ffffff\007'
```

will set the foreground color to white on exit.

Comment: that's it....awesome and pretty easy! and btw. I use nested SSH sessions. I added the  line in the ~./bash_logout as proposed on the remote host and on exit the text color is reset. Do you know by the way what those parameter / command switch like "- n", "-f"... mean?

Comment: @LaUs3r if you're referring to the `-n` in the `[ ... ]` test brackets, they're all documented in the bash shell's internal help under `help test`. In the case of `-n` specifically, it tests for a **n**on-empty string.

Comment: exactly that's what I'm referring to. I will go study that now :)

Comment: What I learnt is, that once you put something into the `.bash_profile`, commands from `.bashrc`are not executed. Originally I had **neofetch** executed everytime I start the bash by putting it at the end of `.bashrc`. Once I created the `.bash_profile`, it didn't work anymore. I needed to move the line from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile

Comment: @LaUs3r if `~/.bash_profile` exists, bash uses it in preference to `~/.profile`. In Ubuntu, the default `~/.profile` conditionally sources `~/.bashrc`. If you want the same behavior when `~/.profile` exists, consider including (i.e. sourcing) `$HOME/.profile` from your `~/.bash_profile`